# Angular Bootstrap UI Timepicker entering invalid time

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-timepicker

I'm using Angular Bootstrap UI Timepicker and if I enter **`50`** in the hours field, it highlights the field red, but nevertheless I get a valid date out of it that looks just like that **`Tue Nov 15 2016 05:00:55 GMT+0100`**.

Any ideas what I can do? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For that matter you could consider to limit the hour and minute input values, here is how to customize it for `Timepicker`

1. introduce a *custom* template and specify the `min`, `max` and `validate-value` attributes for `hour` and `minute` input elements, for example:

```html
<input type="text"  placeholder="HH" validate-value min="1" max="12" ng-model="hours" ng-change="updateHours()" class="form-control text-center" ng-readonly="::readonlyInput" maxlength="2" tabindex="{{::tabindex}}" ng-disabled="noIncrementHours()" ng-blur="blur()">
```

2. implement `validate-value` directive to limit the number values in input element:

```js
.directive('validateValue', function() {
   return {
       require: 'ngModel',
       link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            ngModelCtrl.$parsers.unshift(function(viewValue) {
                var min = Number(eval(attrs.min));
                var max = Number(eval(attrs.max));
                var value = Number(viewValue);
                var valid = (!isNaN(value) && value >= min && value <= max);

                if (!valid) { 
                    var currentValue = ngModelCtrl.$modelValue.toString();
                    ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(currentValue);
                    ngModelCtrl.$render();
                    return currentValue;
                }
                else {
                    return viewValue;
                }
            });
      }
   };
})
```

[**Demo**](https://plnkr.co/edit/JXXo1WDzBqxudxlOOU0k?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks, but is there no "native" way of doing it with simple bootstrap configuration? What you explain here will probably work. I will test it some day soon.

Comment: According to [settings page](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) `max` and `min` could be specified to set maximum and minimum time a user can select but unfortunately those settings will not prevent the user from entering invalid values.

Comment: So I did not try yours. I just console.logged the wrong time object. The result that comes straight from the timepicker seems to be null when invalid. Seems like I used another time object that has been modified before. Thanks anyway and sorry for the efforts.